# Importing from Excel/CSV format to QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, coordinates, import, excel

I created a grid and used it's squares and it has 4 values in  attribute table (each square has **left, top, bottom, and right values**).  Every square is a different object. I try to export file from Excel/CSV, while importing in QGIS, its shows points coordinates **X filed, Y field** and I have (left, top, right, bottom values) 4 points to make it grid (square).

How do I import correctly in QGIS from Excel/CSV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either convert your coordinates to [WellKnownText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) format, or change the layout of your table so each corner of each square has its own row, including a square ID, a point ID and its X and Y coordinates. Duplicate the first point of each square and add it as the fifth.

Your table should look as follows:

| Square ID | Point ID | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | 10 |

Then [load your csv into QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?highlight=import#importing-a-delimited-text-file), run `points to path` and finally convert your `lines to polygons`.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a virtual layer from the information in the excel file.

Add the excel or csv file to the map, and MakePolygon using the four corner coordinates:

```
select MakePolygon( 
    GeomFromText(concat('LINESTRING(',
                "left",' ',"top",
                ',',
                "left",' ',"bottom",
                ',',
                "right",' ',"bottom",
                ',',
                "right",' ',"top",
                ',',
                "left",' ',"top",
                ')'))
                ) as geometry, *
from gridexport
```

Replace `gridexport` with your table name and set the crs in the dialogue:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In MSExcel fill in columns A to H the corner coordinates,  in column I the id that identifies the polygon, create in column J field geom,
calculate geom with the following formula:

```
="POLYGON(("&A2&" "&B2&", "&C2&" "&D2&", "&E2&" "&F2&", "&G2&" "&H2&", "&A2&" "&B2&"))"

LLx LLy LRx LRy URx URy ULx ULy id  geom
-2300   -1000   -1400   -1000   -1400   -400    -2300   -400    block1  POLYGON((-2300 -1000, -1400 -1000, -1400 -400, -2300 -400, -2300 -1000))
-1400   -1000   -500    -1000   -500    -400    -1400   -400    block2  POLYGON((-1400 -1000, -500 -1000, -500 -400, -1400 -400, -1400 -1000))
```

Save as **TAB**separated textfile, and import as WKT in QGIS: Layer > Add layer > add delimited text layer...

Add your exported text file, select File Format: custom delimiters tab, Geometry Definition: Well Known Text, Geometry Field geom and click add.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the numerous solutions proposed, you could use the **Geometry Generator** to create the polygons.

If your CSV-file has the following form:

```
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax
-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5
-2,-1,1,2
...
```

you can load it using QGIS' CSV driver (Select *xmin* and *ymin* for xy):
[image]

Then change the "Simple Marker" styling to "Geometry Generator (Polygon/Multipolygon" and use the following expression to generate your polygons:

```
 geom_from_wkt( 'POLYGON((' ||
 "xmin"||' '||"ymin"||','||
 "xmax"||' '||"ymin"||','||
 "xmax"||' '||"ymax"||','||
 "xmin"||' '||"ymax"||','||
 "xmin"||' '||"ymin"||','||'))')
```

With the processiong tool **"Geometry by expression"** you can save the geometries into a spatial layer.